# Convert Spinner to Date Format in String

Tags: android, string, date, android-spinner

I create a `Spinner` in Android that contains date, month, and year. I want to display the data from `Spinner` into `String` with format `dd/mm/yyyy`. But it always contains error:

```
public static int compare(int lhs, int rhs) {
    return lhs < rhs ? -1 : (lhs == rhs ? 0 : 1);
}

private static NumberFormatException invalidInt(String s) {
    throw new NumberFormatException("Invalid int: \"" + s + "\"");
}
```

Part of my **XML layout**:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/datePayment"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/monthPayment"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/yearPayment"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bsubmit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#6b6b6b"
        android:text="Submit"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/breset"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:background="#6b6b6b"
        android:text="Reset"/> 

</LinearLayout>
```

**Code**

```
public class Payment extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener
{
    private Spinner spDate, spMonth, spYear;
    private static final String[] date = {"01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09",
            "10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24",
            "25","26","27","28","29","30","31"};
    private static final String[] month = {"Januari", "Februari", "Maret", "April",
            "Mei", "Juni", "Juli", "Agustus", "September",
            "Oktober", "November", "Desember"};
    private static final String[] year = {"2014", "2015"};
    private Button bSubmit;
    String tampspDate, tampspMonth, tampspYear, numberMonth, tampNumberMonth;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.payment); 
        spDate =    (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.datePayment);
        spMonth =   (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.monthPayment);
        spYear =    (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.yearPayment);

        ArrayAdapter<String> AdaptDate = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, date);
        AdaptDate.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spDate.setAdapter(AdaptDate);

        ArrayAdapter<String> AdaptMonth = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, month);
        AdaptMonth.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spMonth.setAdapter(AdaptMonth);

        ArrayAdapter<String> AdaptYear = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, year);
        AdaptYear.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spYear.setAdapter(AdaptYear);

        bSubmit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bsubmit);
        spDealer.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        spDate.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        spMonth.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        spYear.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        bSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                tampTanggal = ""+tampspDate+ " "+tampNumberMonth+" "+tampspYear;
                Toast.makeText(Payment.this, tampTanggal, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        tampspDate =   spDate.getSelectedItem().toString();
        tampspMonth = spMonth.getSelectedItem().toString();
        tampspYear =  spYear.getSelectedItem().toString();
        tampNumberMonth = numMonth(tampspMonth);
    }

    public String numMonth(String abc){
        if(abc.equals("Januari")){
            numberMonth="01";
        }
        else if(abc.equals("Februari")){
            numberMonth="02";
        }
        else if(abc.equals("Maret")){
            numberMonth="03";
        }
        else if(abc.equals("April")){
            numberMonth="04";
        }
        else if(abc.equals("Mei")){
            numberMonth="05";
        }
        else if(abc.equals("Juni")){
            numberMonth="06";
        }
        else if(abc.equals("Juli")){
            numberMonth="07";
        }
        else if(abc.equals("Agustus")){
            numberMonth="08";
        }
        else if(abc.equals("September")){
            numberMonth="09";
        }
        else if(abc.equals("Oktober")){
            numberMonth="10";
        }
        else if(abc.equals("November")){
            numberMonth="11";
        }
        else if(abc.equals("Desember")){
            numberMonth="12";
        }
        return numberMonth;
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Comment: Please include the LogCat if the app crashes.

Comment: I guess that you have a nullPointerException ? please attach the stack trace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code may help you to get the date in your required format.

```
final String[] month = {"Januari", "Februari", "Maret", "April", "Mei", "Juni", 
        "Juli", "Agustus", "September", "Oktober", "November", "Desember"};

final String[] date = {"01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09","10","11","12","13","14","15",
        "16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29","30","31"};

final String[] year = {"2014", "2015"};


    // This method identifies the month from the array
    // Use this function instead of numMonth function in your original code. 
    // Its easier to maintain.


public int getMonth(String passedMonth) {
    for (int i = 0; i < month.length; i++) {
        // Returns the array index of the passedMonth from month Array
        if (month[i].equals(passedMonth)) {
            return (i+1);
        }
    }
    return (-1);  // Invalid month
}


   // This method would get the input from your spinner and print the date as
   // per your desired format.

    public void printDateInMyFormat (String date, String month, String year)
   {
            // This is the format you are requesting for.
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

            String dateInString = date +"/"+ getMonth(month) +"/"+ year;
    System.out.println("dateInString : "+dateInString);

    try {

        Date dt = formatter.parse(dateInString);
        System.out.println("My Date ::"+dt);
        System.out.println("My Required Date String :: " +formatter.format(dt));

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

**Results:**

```
Input:
test.printDateInMyFormat ("01", "September", "2015");
```

**Output:**

```
Month is : 9
dateInString : 01/9/2015
My Date :: Tue Sep 01 00:00:00 IST 2015
My Required Date String :: 01/09/2015
```

---

The code handles invalid dates as below:

```
Input:
test.printDateInMyFormat ("31", "September", "2015");
```

**Output:**

```
Month is : 9
dateInString : 31/9/2015
My Date :: Thu Oct 01 00:00:00 IST 2015
My Required Date String :: 01/10/2015
```